# Соотнесение столбцов dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет! Есть два датафрейма с разной структурой:

```
df_old = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','old_col1','old_col2', 'old_col3', 'old_col4'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','col1','col2'])
```

Требуется перенести данные из df_old в df через append по такой логике:

```
df['id'] = df_old['id']
df['col1'] = df_old['old_col2']
df['col2'] = df_old['old_col3']
```

Нужно как то записать эту логику в вызове append, но не понимаю как.
Вариант перестроить df_old не сработает в данной ситуации, так как данные переносятся из df_old в df по определенной логике с использованием append для каждой строки фрейма.
Вызываю данную логику через apply:

```
def makeList(x, course_name):
  if (x['old_col4'] == 1):
    df.append(x) # тут нужно средактировать append так, чтобы df['col1'] соотностился с df_old['old_col2]
  else:
    if (len(df[df['id'] == x['id']]) != 0):
      if (x['old_col2'] == course_name):
        df_result[df_result['id'] == x['id']]['col2'] = x['old_col2']
      else:
        df_result[df_result['id'] == x['id']]['col2'] = x['old_col3']
    else:
      if (x['old_col2'] == course_name):
        df_result.append(x) # тут нужно средактировать append так, чтобы df['col1'] соотностился с df_old['old_col2]
      else:
        df_result.append(x) # тут нужно средактировать append так, чтобы df['col1'] соотностился с df_old['old_col3]
  return x
```

Comment: а зачем, собственно, `append`? Либо вы чего-то не договариваете, и вопрос нужно дополнить, либо приведите живой пример исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: Идея в том, что есть большой фрейм данных, и из него построчно нужно добавить данные в другой более маленький. Столбы нового фрейма заполняются на основе данных из старого по условиям, приведенным в вопросе. Если возможно сделать данную процедуру без построчного перебирания, то буду благодарен. Но на данный момент есть только такая идея.

Comment: Все равно, было бы неплохо показать преобразование на примерах.